# calculate average of the velocity in pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, row

Please give advice. I am newbie in python. I have data looks like this

```
df
ID  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
ID1  2  4   6   8   10
ID2  3  5   7   7   9
ID3  4  6   3   6   8
ID4  5  7   4   5   7
ID5  6  8   5   4   6
ID6  7  9   6   3   5
ID7  8  2   8   2   4
ID8  9  2   7   6   3
ID9  8  4   4   7   6
ID10 9  5   4   8   9
```

I want to analyze average of the data with this equation.

[image: rar]

I used this code:

```
result['Mean'] = result.mean(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
```

I dont know this is good or not.

Comment: Do you understand the mathematical notation?

Comment: What is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide the expected output , base on your equation

```
s=df.iloc[:,1:]
s.shape[1]/(1/s).sum(1)
0    4.379562
1    5.375427
2    4.800000
3    5.343511
4    5.504587
5    5.241265
6    3.333333
7    3.987342
8    5.350318
9    6.271777
dtype: float64
```